# How to save HTML source with filled textareas values DCEF3?

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm using Delphi Chromium Embedded 3 in a project. In this project I load a local HTML file which contain a HTML form. I would like to save whole HTML source with user-filled values.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you've already tried doing this in the demo guiclient.dpr using its GetSource and GetText routines, but found the same as me, i.e. neither of those seem to return the user-filled values?

Comment: I'm looking for TWebBrorser's function. In TWebBrowser:
[code]
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  strCurrrentSource: string;
begin
    Doc:=WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    strCurrentSource:= Doc.body.innerHTML;
[code]

Comment: I could not get HTML code synchronouslyin DCEF.